# What can not I run with HHVM / Laravel?

Tags: laravel, laravel-4, hhvm

I'm developing an application using Laravel framework and using some packagist / composer packages. Will HHVM be able to handle that, I heard that HHVM doesn't run all php functions or something.. 
If no, how can I optimize my app to use HHVM without problems?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Laravel is full supported at HHVM, as you can read at the [list of supported frameworks](http://hhvm.com/frameworks/).

So if you want to run your application on HHVM you must test your code against HHVM. And take care of the used PHP extensions, the number of [extensions supported](https://github.com/facebook/hhvm/wiki/Extensions) by HHVM is growing every day, you maybe some are missing.

Comment: What is not supported? I mean, how can I know if a composer package is not supported before using it?

Comment: Right you cannot, you must test it before. But in a near future if the people use the `hhvm` package at his composer.json, composer can do the job.